# XCode4 - equivalent of old cmd-shift-y

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I used to press cmd-shift-R to see the console in my old XCode, and I used to press cmd-shift-Y to see a screen that would direct to me lines in my code which were causing errors.

How do I do both of these in the new XCode 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button that @Paska is mentioning is the one for your console and log and yes, it is on the top right corner under the view grouping.

For the list of errors you will find a triangular button with an exclamation symbol in it on the group of icons on the left side of your Xcode window right over your project hierarchy. For errors and warnings you can also click on the yellow or red mark that appears on the center top announcement window. If you have any issues with your project it will display yellow and/or red small indicators in this window. You can simply click on these and it will take you to the same issue list.

Answer (score 0):

In this red circle, click the center icon to open log/debug view.

[image]

In log/debug view, use icons on the right to show/hide variables panel.

Comment: first you say click on the icon on the left. then you say click the icon with the bottom border. well...the one with the bottom border is on the right. then you say click the log tab and the center icon? ????????????????? i'm extremely confused

Comment: haha me too :) In the red circle, click the center icon to open log/debug view. In log/debug view, use icons on the right to show/hide variables panel.

Answer (score 0):

`Cmd-Shift-Y` still toggles the Debug area (the area where you see your NSLog, errors, stack trace, etc)

`Cmd-Shift-C` activates the console